# If a function gives error try that iteration again (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, try-catch

There are similar questions on StackOverflow, however, I am failing to find a solution identical (or remotely similar) to my issue. I am running a simulation as follows in R

```
 iterSim <- 1000

 for(i in 1:iterSim){


 #Generate some random data
    Z <- NormalDGP(n=T, beta=coef_min, theta=Theta, rho=Rho, ...)

    y <- Z[1:(length(Z[,1])-1),1]
    x <- Z[2:length(Z[,1]),2]

 #Conduct the following tests! However, Dec_POS_Dep sometimes gives an error

    Dec_POS_Dep <- POS_Dep(y, x, simul=TRUE, trueBeta=coef_min, ...)
    Dec_POS_Fix <- POS_Fix(y, x, simul=TRUE, trueBeta=coef_min, ...)
    Dec_CD_95 <- CD_95(y, x, simul=TRUE)

 }
```

where for each iteration *i* random numbers are generated and three tests are run - i.e., Dec_POS_Dep,Dec_POS_Fix and Dec_CD_95.  Unfortunately, sometimes in the simulation Dec_POS_Dep gives an error and the simulation terminates. I am not looking for the loop to skip an iteration if an error is given (as per many suggestions on StackOverflow); however, I would like that iteration to be repeated. E.g. If the code is on the 265th iteration and Dec_Pos_Dep gives an error, I want it to give it many more shots at the 265th iteration. Some solution to this would very much be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a `try`-function inside a `while`-loop and a `break`-condition, if `Dec_Pos_Dep` succeeds. Don't know, if this is a good way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out as broken here:

1. Use of `try` (as MartinGal suggested) or `tryCatch` will allow things to continue. As far as rerunning that iteration, you'll need to keep track somehow of these failed runs and run them yourself, there's no notion of telling R to repeat a `for` loop iteration.
2. You are discarding data on each iteration, `Dec_CD_95` is overwritten each time. Perhaps you mean to keep things around?

Here's a suggestion:

```r
iterSim <- 1000
out <- list()
while (length(out) < iterSim) {
   try({
     #Generate some random data
     Z <- NormalDGP(n=T, beta=coef_min, theta=Theta, rho=Rho, ...)
     y <- Z[1:(length(Z[,1])-1),1]
     x <- Z[2:length(Z[,1]),2]
     #Conduct the following tests! However, Dec_POS_Dep sometimes gives an error
     Dec_POS_Dep <- POS_Dep(y, x, simul=TRUE, trueBeta=coef_min, ...)
     Dec_POS_Fix <- POS_Fix(y, x, simul=TRUE, trueBeta=coef_min, ...)
     Dec_CD_95 <- CD_95(y, x, simul=TRUE)
     out <- c(out, list(Dec_POS_Dep, Dec_POS_Fix, Dec_CD_95))
  }, silent = TRUE)
}
```

This is a little sloppy, admittedly, but it should always end up with 1000 iterations of your simulation.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Yes my code definitely captures the output, however, I did not include this in my question to keep it short. I appreciate you noticing.